# cancel armor renderer 1.7.10 Minecraft

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

okay i am trying to overwrite the normal armor from Minecraft so 
i need to cancel the armor rendering from normal Minecraft but it is still showing the old armor...

this is how it looks like:
[**this**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAlOH.png) *(i dont want it to render the "big" armor)*

and this is the code i use:

```
package com.bnhc.items;

import com.bnhc.client.render.CArmour;
import com.bnhc.main.Main;

import cpw.mods.fml.relauncher.Side;
import cpw.mods.fml.relauncher.SideOnly;
import net.minecraft.client.model.ModelBiped;
import net.minecraft.entity.Entity;
import net.minecraft.entity.EntityLivingBase;
import net.minecraft.entity.player.EntityPlayer;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemArmor;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemStack;

public class CCloth extends ItemArmor {

    public CCloth(ArmorMaterial material, int armorType, int armorIndex) {
        super(material, armorType, armorIndex);
    }

    public String getArmorTexture(ItemStack itemstack, Entity entity, int slot, String layer) { 
        if(((itemstack.getItem() == MIte.ua_sports_layer_1) || (itemstack.getItem() == MIte.ua_sports_layer_1))){
            return "bnhc:textures/armour/uasports_layer_1.png"; 
        } 
        return null;
    }

    CArmour armorModel = new CArmour(0.0F);

    @Override
    @SideOnly(Side.CLIENT)
    public ModelBiped getArmorModel(EntityLivingBase entityLiving, ItemStack itemStack, int armorSlot) {

        if (itemStack != null) {
            if (itemStack.getItem() instanceof CCloth) {
                int type = ((ItemArmor)itemStack.getItem()).armorType;

                if (type == 1) {
                    armorModel = Main.proxy.getArmorModel(0);
                } else {
                    armorModel = Main.proxy.getArmorModel(1);
                }
            }
            if (armorModel != null) {
                armorModel.isSneak = entityLiving.isSneaking();
                armorModel.isRiding = entityLiving.isRiding();
                armorModel.isChild = entityLiving.isChild();
                armorModel.heldItemRight = entityLiving.getEquipmentInSlot(0) != null ? 1 :0;
                if(entityLiving instanceof EntityPlayer) {
                    armorModel.aimedBow =((EntityPlayer)entityLiving).getItemInUseDuration() > 2;
                }
                return armorModel;
            }
        }
        return armorModel;
    }
}
```

and this is in my client proxy:

```
@Override
public CArmour getArmorModel(int id) {
    return customArmour;
}
```

-edit
okay i got it working .. basicly what i did wrong was its already gets rendered by default by making it a "ModelBiped" *(please correct me if i am wrong)* so all i had to do is deleting the client proxy stuff ...

this is how it looks like now (**the fixed version**):

```
package com.bnhc.items;

import com.bnhc.CreativeTabs.CTBS;
import com.bnhc.main.Ref;

import cpw.mods.fml.relauncher.Side;
import cpw.mods.fml.relauncher.SideOnly;
import net.minecraft.client.model.ModelBiped;
import net.minecraft.entity.Entity;
import net.minecraft.entity.EntityLivingBase;
import net.minecraft.entity.player.EntityPlayer;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemArmor;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemStack;

public class CCloth extends ItemArmor {

    public CCloth(ArmorMaterial armorMaterial, int renderindex, int armortype,String name) {
        super(armorMaterial, renderindex, armortype);
        }   


    public String getArmorTexture(ItemStack stack, Entity entity, int slot, String type) {
        if(stack.getItem() == MIte.ua_sports_chest) {
            return Ref.MODID+ ":textures/armour/uasports_layer_1.png";
        }else if(stack.getItem() == MIte.ua_sports_leggs){
            return Ref.MODID+ ":textures/armour/uasports_layer_2.png";
        }else {
            return null;
        }
    }


            ModelBiped armorModel = new ModelBiped();

            @Override
            @SideOnly(Side.CLIENT)
            public ModelBiped getArmorModel(EntityLivingBase entityLiving,
        ItemStack itemStack, int armorSlot) {

            if(itemStack != null){
            if(armorModel != null){
                armorModel.bipedRightLeg.showModel = armorSlot == 2;
                armorModel.bipedLeftLeg.showModel = armorSlot == 2;
                armorModel.bipedBody.showModel = armorSlot == 1;
                armorModel.bipedRightArm.showModel = armorSlot == 1;
                armorModel.bipedLeftArm.showModel = armorSlot == 1;
                armorModel.bipedHead.showModel = armorSlot == 0;

                armorModel.isSneak = entityLiving.isSneaking();
                armorModel.isRiding = entityLiving.isRiding();
                armorModel.isChild = entityLiving.isChild();
                armorModel.heldItemRight = entityLiving.getEquipmentInSlot(0) != null ? 1 :0;
            if(entityLiving instanceof EntityPlayer){
                 armorModel.aimedBow =((EntityPlayer)entityLiving).getItemInUseDuration() > 2;
                }
             return armorModel;
            }
        }
     return armorModel;
    }
}
```

i deleted my stuff in the client proxy because it is unneeded with the @SideOnly annotation and rendered it 2 times ..

Comment: @will-m thx for the formatting suggestion

Comment: Your client proxy is useless, because you will always return `customArmour`. You you might as well just remove the switch part and return the variable.

Comment: thanks i just was about to try around with the client method because i thought returning it 2 times is making no sense..

Comment: anyways this is not doing anything (of course if i return it 2 times the 2nd will just overwrite the first and because they are the same = no change at all)

Comment: Of course it doesn't change anything to the execution. I was not giving you an answer to your issue, I was just commenting on the fact that your switch statement was useless. For your actual question, I don't know much about Minecraft modding, I still suggest double-checking the custom texture if it is correct (in case you took the original as template)

Comment: okay sure i will do that .. but i guess its not the texture. I am thinking of that my method does NOT cancel the normal minecraft armor renderer what would cause my issue. I am asking for help how to cancel that renderer because i could not find any information how to do this in the internet or the minecraft / minecraft forge source code..

anyways thanks even doe you dont know minecraft modding @Seblor

Comment: You solved your problem, perhaps it could be useful to add an answer yourself and accept it for future readers (with potentially the same problem). This is perfectly acceptable on Stack Overflow.

Comment: okay i will do that @Vallas